# minimal os and desktop environment

Tags: 17.10, kde

I'm using KDE for 2 years now and i just realized i'm basically using just the krunner and nothing else. Is it possible to remove everything, the bottom bar, the activites and basically everything except the krunner?

The other thing is, there is a lot of software installed by default like libre office which i'm never using.

Basically what i want is a bloatless OS, a window manager and krunner.

Comment: No, don't think so. Krunner seems to be a part of KDE Plasma, it is not a separate package, so there seems to be no way to install just it. You can remove Libre Office though.

Comment: `apt-file search --regexp '/krunner$'` identifies `plasma-workspace` as the package providing `krunner`.

Comment: if i kill the plasma process krunner keeps working though, why is it like that?

Comment: What exact process do you kill? Some processes restart themselves. Anyway, to partly answer your question, you can't just have a bloatless OS with kwin as a window manager. I just tried with a ubuntu minimal iso. You'll have better luck with Openbox which can run without a desktop.